# Asynchronous pinging

Tags: c#, events, asynchronous, ping

Ran into a weird "problem". Have an application that pingsweeps entire networks. Works great until you get to a network with 255.255.0.0 netmask (which is 65k + addresses).

I send my pings like this:

```
    foreach (string str in ListContainingAddresses)
        {
            using (Ping ping = new Ping())
            {
                if (pingCounter == 10000) { Thread.Sleep(10000); pingCounter = 0; }
                //Make an eventhandler
                ping.PingCompleted += new PingCompletedEventHandler(pingCompleted);
                //Send the pings asynchronously
                ping.SendAsync(IPAddress.Parse(str), 1000);
                sentPings++;

                //This counts pings being sent out
                pingCounter++;
            }
        }
```

And recive them like this:

```
    public void pingCompleted(object sender, PingCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //This counts recieved addresses 
        recievedIpAddresses++;

        if (e.Reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
        {
            //Do something
        }
        else
        {
            /*Computer is down*/
        }
        //This checks if sent equals recieved
        if (recievedIpAddresses == sentPings )
        {
            //All returned
        }
    }
```

Problem is that a) Sometimes (very rarely) it doesnt complete (Condition not met). b) When it does complete the numbers dont match? If i print sent and recieved just now they are

```
    Sent: 65025 Recieved: 64990
```

Despite this the condition is met and application moves on? I dont know why and how this is happening. Is the code executing to fast for the application to update two ints? Do some pings get lost along the way? If I try it on a subnetwork with 255 addresses this problem never happens.
Cant use CountDownEvent instead of variables since its .NET 3.5

Comment: My money would be on thread safety.

Even though it would slow things down a little, I would concentrate on making pingCompleted thread-safe.

Comment: stupid question: why not use [`nmap`](http://nmap.org/download.html)? I bet it will be fastest solution possible

Comment: Not stupid at all, I want to learn how to do it myself, simple as that :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you have any locking in place at all? That looks like your problem to me. I can see all sorts of [race conditions and memory processor cache issues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1c9txz50.aspx) potentially in your code.

Try using [`lock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) for protecting the `recievedIpAddresses == sentPings` and

```
sentPings++;
//This counts pings being sent out
pingCounter++;
```

#### Using `lock`

For instance:

```
private readonly object SyncRoot = new object();

public void MainMethod()
{
    foreach (string str in ListContainingAddresses)
    { ... }
    lock (SyncRoot) { sentPings++; }
    ....
}

public void pingCompleted(object sender, PingCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //This counts recieved addresses 
    lock (SyncRoot) { recievedIpAddresses++; } // lock this if it is used on other threads

    if (e.Reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
    {
        //Do something
    }
    else
    {
        /*Computer is down*/
    }
    lock (SyncRoot) { // lock this to ensure reading the right value of sentPings
        //This checks if sent equals recieved
        if (recievedIpAddresses == sentPings )
        {
            //All returned
        }
    }
}
```

The above sample will force reads and writes from shared memory so that different CPU cores aren't reading different values. However, depending on your code you may need much more coarse grained locking, where the first loop protects both `sentPings` and `pingCounter` in one `lock`, and maybe even the second method is completely protected with a `lock`.

People can say not to use `lock` as it causes performance issues, and lock free is very trendy. The bottom line is `lock` is simpler than other alternatives most of the time. You may need to make your locking more coarse grained than the above sample because you potentially have race conditions as well. It's hard to give a better sample without seeing your entire program.

#### `Interlocked.Increment`

The main reason to use `lock` here is to force each read and write to come from memory, not CPU cache, and therefore you should get consistent values. An alternative to lock is to use [Interlocked.Increment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd78zt0c.aspx), but if you use that on two separate variables you need to watch carefully for race conditions.

#### Race conditions

(Edit)

Even if you lock you potentially have a problem. Watch this timeline for 13 target addresses (unlucky for some). If you aren't comfortable with why this is, then have a look at ["Managed Threading Basics"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hyz69czz.aspx) and ["Threading in C# - Joseph Albahari"](http://www.albahari.com/threading/)

- T1: 1 time

  - T1: Ping sent
  - T1: `sentPings++`
- T2: 1 time

  - recievedIpAddresses++;
  - T2: other stuff
- meanwhile T1: 12 times

  - T1: Ping sent
  - T1: `sentPings++` (now equal to 13)
- T2: `recievedIpAddresses == sentPings` test - now fails as they are not equal
- T3 through to T14: enters `pingCompleted` and does `recievedIpAddresses++;`
- T1 finishes, application gets to writing out the ping counts (or worse still exits entirely) before the other 12 threads have returned in the background

You need to watch carefully for this type of race condition in your code, and adjust it accordingly. The whole thing about threads is that they overlap their operations.

#### SyncRoot

*Footnote*:

Why is `SyncRoot` declared as: `private readonly object SyncRoot = new object();`?

- It is a class field to protect class fields, if you have a `static` console app, it will need to be `static`. But, if you use `static` in a class, then every instance will lock on the same object, so there will be contention
- It is `readonly` to declare intent, and prevent you (or other team members) overwriting it later
- It is an `object` as:

  - you don't need anything other than an object
  - you can't lock on a value type
  - you shouldn't lock your class instance (to prevent [deadlocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1c9txz50.aspx) in more complicated code)
  - you shouldn't make it public (also to prevent deadlocks)
- It is instantiated along with the class (in a thread safe manner) by this statement
- It is called `SyncRoot` as an example; Visual Studio has historically called it that in it's snippets

Comment: Actually never heard of lock, gonna look into it.

Comment: Or use the Interlocked class for incrementing integer variables that could be accessed from multiple threads at the same time.

Comment: @Gvs. Added reference links for you. Dirk, agreed, though need to be careful of race conditions with `Interlocked`. Coarse grained locking can be simpler.

Comment: @Gvs. Also, I have just added an edit showing how race conditions could bite you if the code you haven't shown us doesn't protect you against them. There are two valuable references in that edit that can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent explanation. But this makes it painfully obvious on how little I know :p. Just adding a Console.Writeline on the counter variables messes things up aswell. If I just do one print on sent and recieved after the finish condition is met it all works fine. Well I guess I have alot of reading to do on this subject :).

Comment: About your race conditions, even if thread1 increments sentPings and thread2 increments recievedPings, doesnt the ping.Async spawn threads and also manage them? Even if T1 increments one value and T2 the other shouldnt it even out so to speak in the end?

Comment: @Gvs. `ping.SendAsync` is a "fire and forget", you could end up queueing 100 pings immediately, and then ending up with 100 `pingCompleted` methods running at the same time on different threads. Does that answer your question? As for how that would work in your program, I can't tell as I don't know what you are doing in side your `if` statements. Potentially your program could exit before 5 of them come back, or they might complete before you exit if on your main thread you wait until you have received as many as sent.

Comment: That explains it more clearly, what I do inside the statements is, fire an event if the pingsweep is complete, add to a list if the ping is succesful and dont do anything if the ping is unsuccessful.